# MaprStream with spring integration Kafka Producer issue

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-kafka, mapr-streams

I am using mapr-stream with spring integration and trying to create a publisher to send messages to maprstream topics. I am using the below Jar version compatibility matrix mentioned [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-kafka/).

**Spring-integration-kafka - 2.0.1.RELEASE

Spring-Kafka  - 1.0.3.RELEASE

Kafka-clients - 0.9.0.0-mapr-1607**

As mentioned in the spring integration Kafka [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-integration-kafka/2.0.1.RELEASE/api/), I should be able to set the property '**sync**' in KafkaProducerMessageHandler if I am using **spring-integration-kafka-2.0.1** jar,
but I am getting the schema validation issues saying the 'sync' is not expected in the KafkaProducerMessageHandler.

Could someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML Namespace support for `sync` was [not added until 2.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/pull/144/commits/aea4b2355ac9e61776f001ab092e933e4b7e1d99).

With 2.0.x, you have to set the property on the `KafkaProducerMessageHandler` bean programmatically.

**EDIT**

```
@Autowired
private KafkaProducerMessageHandler handler;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.handler.setSync(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gary for the update. But would you please provide a sample snippet for it as I am not able to set this variable. Also assuming that we will be able to achieve the actual use case of 'sync' if we set this variable programmatically.

Comment: See my edit; if you have multiple handlers you will have to use a `@Qualifier` with the bean name, which is the adapters id + ".handler".

Comment: Thanks for the update. Would I be able to set this property in the below code snippet as I am using xml configuration in our project.
`<int:chain input-channel="inputToKafka">
        <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter"
                                    kafka-template="template"
                                    topic="${maprstream.stream.topicname}"
                                     >
                             
</int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>
</int:chain>`

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking; the XML support was not added until 2.1. If you add another bean with the code I provided, it will set the flag for you. Add `<context:annotation-config/>` and `<bean class="foo.bar.MySyncSetter"/>`.

Comment: Yes..I got it..and its working as expected now..!I can see the performance variation if we enable sync as true..! Thanks